# Function has a return, where it return to? Who is holding it? How long it lives?

Tags: swift, function, return

I'm always curious what's going on with the return value from a function if I simply call the function without passing it into variables.  Where is it returned to? Who is holding it? How long will it hold?

The example below is written by Swift

```
func returnFun(input: String) -> String {
    return(input)
}

returnFun("Who Am I?")
```

`returnFun` is the name of the function and it returns any strings you put into the argument as the string itself. the string **Who Am I?** had been put into the argument, where does it go? Who catches it? Or it will be destroyed right after returning?

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: are you familiar with [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)?

Comment: @Will Ness No I'm not familiar Call Stack at all. Thanks for providing a studying direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not store (or otherwise use) a function return value, it will just be discarded.

The process is that the function provides its return value to the caller (usually via CPU registers or the stack), and it is up to the caller to pick it up from there.

---

Things get a bit more interesting when values are larger than a "machine word" (something that fits in a single register), such as structs or strings (as in your example). Those might require need to passed around as pointers to memory locations elsewhere, and that memory needs to be managed (allocated and released) somehow.

The main conceptual distinction here is between "value types" and "reference types". A Swift string is a value type, which means that it gets copied (at least conceptually, implementation may be different to be more efficient, as long as it results in the same observable behaviour). So you can think of the string being copied from the caller into a local variable `input` for the function once when you call the function and copied again when it is returned (and not immediately discarded).

Comment: If the caller decides not to pick it up it will be still there until the "space" is occupied by other returns or just simply destroyed

Comment: The return value will be calculated and stored "for pickup" even if it is never used (unless the compiler does some really clever tricks). But that space will be reused for other things almost immediately.

Comment: Again, things get a bit more complex with "reference types". There only the reference gets passed in and out of functions, many references can point to the same thing, and memory management gets complicated (Swift uses reference counting, other environment have garbage collection).

Comment: Thanks Thilo, the explanation is very nice and clear. I'm a programming starter. Mostly I learn it by myself.  I lack the systematic  knowledge about the concept of Subroutine, Stack, Register, compiling, reference etc. What kind of book your were reading? Would you mind recommend me some books of the basic, core part of the computer programming/science, I would very appreciate.

Comment: Take a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86530/learning-computer-architecture-as-a-programmer

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot